# Как кодить в online режиме на nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, администрирование

Мне нужно знать, как Вы разрабатываете скрипты.
Например, я работаю через `putty` - внес изменения в коде `nodejs`, зашел в `putty` написал `node script.js start`. Это действие приходится выполнять каждый раз заново, а то и приходится выходить из `putty` и заново заходить.

Дорогие разработчики `nodejs`-a, скажите, как легко кодить в `online` режиме на `nodejs`?

***Добавлю еще один вопрос к первому вопросу.***

Как остановить скрипт `node server.js`, запущенный для `socket.io`? Он работает всегда со старым кодом, я не знаю, как запустить новый код на `server.js`.

`node.js` и `socket.io` мне конкретно по выносили мозг в плане администрирования.

Comment: "Добавлю еще один вопрос к первому вопросу." Да вы сговорились что-ли? Неужели так сложно задать 2 вопроса. Какое отношение имеет первый вопрос ко второму?

По поводу онлайн кодинга - практически не вижу этому применения, разве-что верстка, вьюшки, но это не совсем программирование и уж точно не node.js.

"Как остановить скрипт node server.js запущенный для socket.io?" Если вы не знаете ответа на этот элементарный вопрос, то админ из вас... ну в общем не лучший :)

По нормальному люди сначала пишут код, а потом отлаживают. Но вот отладка !== то, о чем писали вы

Answer (score 1):

[node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)

Answer (score 0):

[cloud9ide](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) +  что-нибудь для [перезапуска](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-restarting)

Answer (score 0):

[Описание работы с `node-supervisor`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aViNktk1ck)